# Languages that have phonemic aspirated post-alveolar affricates

Tags: list-of-languages, aspiration, phoneme-inventories, affricates

There are loads of languages that have *voiceless post-alveolar affricate*, **tʃ**. I am aware of languages that have phonemic voiceless plosives (e.g. Mandarin), but I am wondering if there are any languages that have *phonemic* **aspirated voiceless post-alveolar affricate**, **[tʃʰ]**. Is there any language that has it?

Comment: Would you count systems that distinguish voices unaspirated [dʒ] and unvoiced aspirated [tʃʰ]? For a language like English, which pairs like that, the voicing it usually taken to be the primary phonemic factor, but for a language like Danish, it’s aspiration. Phoible doesn’t have Danish in its list, but both /tʃ/ and /tʃʰ/ are common enough in English loan words (e.g., _joke_ [tʃɔ̞ʊɡ̊] vs. _chill_ [tʃe̞l]). It’s perfectly arguable that they’re phonemic, although they’re often subsumed under /dj/ and /tj/.

Comment: The Hindustani language (aka Hindi and Urdu) has it, plus it is in contrast with the unaspirated unvoiced post-alveolar affricate /tʃ/.

Comment: (My transcription of _chill_ above should have read [tʃʰe̞l], of course, with the aspiration. More accurately described, the pair is actually [d̥ʒ̊(ʰ)], since all Danish consonants are lenis.)

Answer (score 3):

You can search for the segment [tʃʰ] at [Phoible](https://phoible.org/parameters/9C6117430968F42700ACD02E4E7442F7#2/24.2/161.3) and get quite an impressive list of languages having it. Clicking on [Mundari](https://phoible.org/inventories/view/602) as a randomly chosen example confirms that it contrasts with non-aspirated [tʃ] in that language.

Answer (score 2):

Sanskrit, and most other Indian languages, have (at least in the script) a four-way distinction of c - ch - j - jh. I would have to rummage a bit in the dictionary to establish minimal pairs.

Comment: I don't know how much phonetic detail the OP is interested in, but it's worth noting that (at least for Sanskrit) these are usually described as palatal stops rather than affricates.

Comment: Theoretically, they are unit phonemes. In practice, they're clusters for some people, sometimes, in some sentences, and not others. Just like /tʃ/'s in _Gotcha, Charlie!_

Comment: Saraiki would be an example of an Indic language in which phonemic [tʃʰ] has been conserved where it occurs. In Punjabi it is present but interestingly it has become an allophone with [ʃ] for many speakers.